# What is difference between '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)' and '@item.FirstName'?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
```

and

```
@item.FirstName
```

Which is the preferred way? Which is best and how?

Answer (score 1):

DisplayFor is what is known as a display templates and have existed for a long time in mvc. They are to be used when you want to use an objects metadata for consideration when displaying in the view.

**Update**: @stephen-muecke is correct in the comments. Original answer was incorrect.

When you use `HTML.DisplayFor(m=> mi.FirstName)` it will display the value along with the formatting specified in the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute for that property. Whereas, `@item.FirstName` will not take into account the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute and will display the value of the object.

<del>When you use `HTML.DisplayFor(m=> mi.FirstName)` it will display `First Name` whereas `@item.FirstName` will not take into account the display attribute and will display the value of the object.</del>

Now, if you are using aspnet core you should read up on TagHelpers and use that approach. It's much cleaner and the "aspnet core" way of doing it. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) and look at any of the aspnet core templates.

Comment: Your confusing `DisplayFor()` with `DisplayNameFor()` (`DisplayFor()` will not render "First Name" - it renders the value of the property (formatted in accordance with any `[DisplayFormat]` attribute